# Two-way data-binding on XML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, data-binding, aurelia

I've just started working with Aurelia, so I would appreciate a little help regarding databinding.

I have a site that lets user create and edit a set of elements on the page. When a save is triggered, this page will translate the elements into an XML string and sent to the server. But what I would really like is to have a data-binding between the view and the XML, or at least the viewmodel and the XML, so I can inspect the resulting XML instantly on any changes I make to the elements. Do I have to parse an XML string back and forth for every change I make to the elements? How can Aurelia know to change the view if I change the XML? Is it easier to data-binding it with Json instead of XML, and then just translate json to XML upon change to monitor the result?

Comment: Since there are easy tools to convert from JSON to JavaScript objects and handle those server side my thoughts always go that way for the UI to back end layers.  Not saying that XML is not viable, it just seems like a "heavier" method for applications and UI as opposed to heavily nested data tree transports that can be represented in XML easily.  For example quick, tell me 2 XML to data on client side technologies...see what I mean.

Comment: Indeed! But unfortunately, I'm bound to store the elements in the XML format, because I share this data with a different application, and it doesn't support json.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the correct answer is "don't do it"
You are asking to bring a lot of pain on yourself.

I have no doubt that it is possible to write generic engine to have a synced version of XML<->JSON
But as long as it is your code, you will have to maintain it for the life of your app.
I bet you don't share the data between apps without backend.

Server side frameworks and languages are far more capable of transforming data between formats. You also would not have to implement real time synchronization on the fly.
For example asp.net mvc core or otherwise can accept request data in json and in xml and also send it out in those formats. You don't even have to care what app posts what.

You can have a logic added to any server side technology stack to parse data based on content-type.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm not going to invent a whole framework for my purpose, just looking to see if there were any common practices for this out there already. Unfortunately, I need to switch between this "xml view" and the visual representation on the fly, so I believe converting back and fourth server side might make things complex and I would rather not have to maintain a lot of server side code as well. I think that the best way to for me to proceed is to keep XML out of the bindings, but on demand, build an XML in browser to present to the user (two way) and/or submit to server.

Comment: do you need to be able to edit xml or just render it ?
Just found a library to convert json to xml
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-xml-parser